# How can I export the execution of a command to an upstart script

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, environment-variables, upstart

I have an `upstart` script that runs a *nodejs-app*, but `Node.js` is installed with `nvm`. I source some variables to `upstart` from another file, and my `script` section looks like this:

```
script

. /etc/default/nodejs

exec start-stop-daemon --start  --make-pidfile --pidfile /var/run/app.pid
--chdir /home/node-apps/ --chuid root:root
--exec $NODE_NVM_PATH app.js >> /var/log/node/app.log 2>&1

end script
```

In `/etc/default/nodejs` *(chmod 744)* I have this:

```
NODE_NVM_PATH=$(which node)
```

with the idea that `which node` outputs the nodejs' path installed via `nvm`; because if I update or change the `Node.js` version, I don't want to edit the new path in this file.

But using this method, don't works and my `app.js` it is not running. I have also tried `export NODE_NVM_PATH=$(which node)`, and the same result.

But if I put:

```
NODE_NVM_PATH="/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.2.0/bin/node"
```

inside `/etc/default/nodejs` everything works perfectly.

**So my question is:**

How can I get the execution of a `which node` in this other file and source it to upstart?

**NOTES:**

- I have also an *enviromment variable* called `$NVM_BIN` that outputs the nodejs'path, but don't know also how to source it to upstart.
- The `exec` instructions in deed, are only in one line; I pasted here in separated lines to avoid scrolling

Answer (score 0):

try backquotes " ` " instead of   $( )

```
NODE_NVM_PATH=$(which node)

NODE_NVM_PATH=`which node`

echo ${NODE_NVM_PATH}
```

you can let us know what it does.

Comment: I have put **NODE_NVM_PATH=`which node`**  o my `/etc/default/nodejs`. If I run it with `./etc/default/nodejs` works (same than before), but does not works inside `upstart`, and that is what I need.

Comment: some others ideas? :)